# Last quarter 'float shares' data not accessible in Pine

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Is there any way to get the last quarter value for the `FLOAT_SHARES_OUTSTANDING` metric, in Pine Script?

I am asking because in the ['Key stats' financial section of TradingView](https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/NYSE-V/financials-statistics-and-ratios/), this value is clearly listed under the 'Float shares outstanding‪' row. The column is called 'Current' (last column), and it lists the last quarter value for the current year.

Still, in [the section that lists the financial data accessible in Pine](https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000564727-what-financial-data-is-available-in-pine/), the `FLOAT_SHARES_OUTSTANDING` entry has only one period: FY (Financial Year). So, no quarterly data for this metric, yet the last quarter data point is available through the website.

Thank you!

Alex

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")
plot(request.financial(syminfo.tickerid, "TOTAL_SHARES_OUTSTANDING", "FQ"))
```

Comment: I was referring to 'FLOAT_SHARES_OUTSTANDING', not 'TOTAL_SHARES_OUTSTANDING'.

Comment: in the 'Key stats' financial section of TradingView there are only FLOAT_SHARES_OUTSTANDING FY data

Comment: Andrey, [please see this screen shot](https://ibb.co/G7wXxMb) so you can better understand what I'm referring to. In the 'Annual' section of the '[Key stats](https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/NYSE-V/financials-statistics-and-ratios/)', you will see a 'Current' column which shows the last quarterly value for some metrics. At this time, that field shows '1.63B‬' for Visa, and it's not an annual value, because the last annual value is 1.67B. I also double-checked that in Pine Script (using a FY 'request.financial'). Anyway, I wonder how I can get that '1.63B‬' (current) value via Pine Script.

Comment: I've talked with responsible for financial data team. There `Current` for FLOAT_SHARES_OUTSTANDING value is not available through request.security unfortunately (

Comment: All right, I understand! Thank you very much for taking the time to look into this issue.